# Reverse Proxy htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to setup a Reverse Proxy on my server i.e.

From: http://info.futures.co.uk/info/sitemap.xml

To:   http://api.info.futures.co.uk/sitemap.xml

I would like to do this in ,htaccess. Did some research on google and found this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html/(http://info.futures.co.uk/info/sitemap.xml)$ $1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html/http://api.info.futures.co.uk/sitemap.xml)$ $1 [P,L]
```

Firstly I dont understand this code secondly it does not work..? Is there a better way or am doing some mistake here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will proxy info/sitemap.xml to http://api.info.futures.co.uk/sitemap.xml, but only this file (images and so on will not be displayed):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^info/sitemap.xml http://api.info.futures.co.uk/sitemap.xml [P]
```

This will proxy all pages in info to http://api.info.futures.co.uk/:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^info/(.*) http://api.info.futures.co.uk/$1 [P]
```

Please remember to enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http in httpd.conf!

Use this with caution!

If http://api.info.futures.co.uk is available to the client I suggest not to proxy and use a redirect instead.

Comment: Redirects (see https://serverfault.com/questions/895282/configuring-reverse-proxy-with-mod-proxy-rules-using-only-htaccess-file) and links within the pages may still pojnt to api.info.futures.co.uk.

Comment: this also made my nodejs reverse proxy work as my host is using cpanel and it would be so much trouble to locate the ssl certificates.

```https://example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js```
points to
```http://example.com:50000/socket.io/socket.io.js```

where my node-app is using port 50000, running with expressjs and socket.io. works like a charm!